# Css Hyperlink font color not changing

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have seen similar posts ..I have modified my code and currently using  this Code to add color to Hyperlink Text..
My Hyperlink generates at runtime in HTML output..
I have multiple css ..I think css effects are overriding

```
a:link
{
   color: red;
   color: inherit;
   text-decoration:underline;
}
```

also tried this one :

```
a:link
{
   color: #fff; 
     text-decoration:underline;
}
```

My Script:

```
function (response) {            
        obj =response.d;
        var output = "<table class='table'><tr><th>Serial No.</th><th>UFZillaID</th><th>MZillaID</th><th>Status</th></tr>";

        for (var x = 0; x < obj.length; x++) {

            output += "<tr><td >" + obj[x].EMID + "</td></tr>";
        }
        output += "</table>";
        $("#result").append(output);
```

this is my markup

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UFZillaErrorStatus.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="Dashboard.Web.UFZillaErrorStatus" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>UFZillaErrorStatus</title>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800|Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700"
        rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link href="css/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="js/common/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.4/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/common/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.4/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/common/jquery/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/common/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/common/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.4/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/common/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.4/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/common/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.4/plugins/grid.postext.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/JqueryFileupload/jquery.fileupload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/JqueryFileupload/jquery.iframe-transport.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/common/jquery/jquery.alphanumeric.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/dashboard/UFZillaErrorStatus.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

        });


    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="content1" style="background: 0 0 0 #FFFFF">
        <div id="uferrdivs" align="center">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Product
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select id="proselct">
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <center>
                <div>
                    <div id="result" style="background-color: #F5F5F5; width: 800px; margin-top: 50px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

..Underline effect appears..But color not changing ..I have tried other method .But Not working ...

Any Suggestion would be helpful

Comment: What color you want to apply? white?

Comment: Can u pls create a fiddle to test?

Comment: What is the background color of the page? if it is white, link will not be visible.

Comment: I also tried red.It is not working ...I edited my code

Comment: Did you apply any other css class to link?

Comment: yes .i am posting full aspx page

Comment: style="background: 0 0 0 #FFFFF"... change it to `#FFFFFF`

Comment: Can you post dynamically generated hyperlink coding...

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
color: inherit;
```

As this is overriding your colour that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your  tag contains

```
href="#"
```

At minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Try simplest way

use this css

```
a, a * {
    color: #FFF !important; // important will avoid if any other css try to override it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your background color is `WHITE`, link will not be visible. Because you set the same color for link

> color: #FFF;

Try with different color

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

```
color: inherit;
```

and see it will work.

Simple demo of both

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3428/1/)** using inherit

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3428/2/)** without using inherit